# How to use FFmpeg(v 4.0) HwAccell in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm making an app that uses FFmpeg on Android to show the screen.

I have a few questions to ask you.

```
std::vector <AVHWDeviceType> GetSupportHwDeviceType ()
{
    unsigned int idx {};
    std::vector <AVHWDeviceType> hwDevTypes;

    AVHWDeviceType hwDevType = AVHWDeviceType::AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE;
    while ((hwDevType = av_hwdevice_iterate_types (hwDevType)) ! = AVHWDeviceType::AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE)
    {
        __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, __func__, "[Index% d]", idx ++);
        __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, __func__,
                        "[Support Device Name% s]", av_hwdevice_get_type_name (hwDevType));

        hwDevTypes.push_back (hwDevType);
    }

    return hwDevTypes;
}
```

I would like to use hardware acceleration with the above function, and as a result I could not find any type.

At https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro, it says that Android can use MediaCodec. Why can not I retrieve any type from Android NDK with GetSupportHwDeviceType ()?

The Configure argument used while building FFmpeg for Android.

```
--disable-asm
--enable-cross-comile
--disable-static
--disable-programs
--disable-doc
--enable-shared
--enable-protocol=file
--enable-pic
--enable-small
--enable-mediacodec
--enable-jni
--enable-decoder=h264_mediacodec
--enable-opengl

/* The argument was not supported by ./configure --list-hwaccel in FFmpeg v4.0.3. */

--enable-hwaccel=h264_mediacodec
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?